# Evaluating $\int_{B^n(1)}e^{-|\vec{x}|}\frac{\cos|\vec{x}|}{\left(\sum_{m=2}^{n}x_{m}^2\right)^{(n-2)/2}}\,\mathrm{d}^nx$

Tags: integration, special-functions

$$ \int_{B^n(1)}e^{-|\vec{x}|}\frac{\cos|\vec{x}|}{\left(\sum_{m=2}^{n}x_{m}^2\right)^{(n-2)/2}}\,\mathrm{d}^nx $$

The problem is to calculate this integral and express the solution as Beta and/or Gamma functions, and the domain of integral is the $n$-dimensional ball with radius $1$.

Comment: Are you sure the summation is supposed to start at $2$?

Comment: Yes I looked the problem on the pdf again and the sum starts at m=2

Comment: There is maybe some hope if the summation starts at $1$ but starting at $2$ this integral is basically unapproachable.

Comment: I will look it up tomorrow and I will let you know :)

Comment: Yes the sum, indeed starts at m=2

Comment: In hyperspherical coordinates, we obtain
$$S_{n - 2} \int_0^\pi \int_0^1
 \frac {e^{-\rho} \cos \rho} {(\rho^2 - (\rho \cos \theta)^2)^{(n - 2)/2}}
 \rho^{n - 1} \sin^{n - 2} \theta \, d\rho d\theta.$$
The remaining integral is elementary.

Comment: I can tell the integral is to be converted jn n hyper spherical but i the jacobian adds a product of dφi (except φ=1) and I cant understand why is this the solution you take...

Comment: I mean what happens to d^nx and why dont you come up with a triple integral?

Comment: The integral over the other angles is the surface area of a hypersphere.

Comment: Could you write what you mean in Latex? My english are very poor so I am not so sure if I understand what you mean. If its inconvenientfor you, then dont:)

Comment: Compare the Jacobian with the [area element of an $(n - 2)$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_and_area_elements) in spherical coordinates.

Comment: I am sorry but , its too complicated when I trt to continue your solution...if you find time maybe you could write the whole solution in more depth as an answer. Thanks!!